# Angularjs (phonegap) and socket.io

Tags: angularjs, cordova, sockets

How exactly should I go about this when implementing the listener? I do my connection with `socket = new socket(url,...` but would need this variable to be accessed within my main controller (where I open the connection) as well as within the code where I implement the listener. But **how** exactly? Should I implement the listener `socket.on("some_message,...` within a separate controller? Can this controller access any element in the UI for interaction? Or should I implement my socket code as a service in angularjs? Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to have a look at [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io), this library is an angular wrapper for socket.io, there are plenty of examples of how to do such a thing in there documentation.

If you decide to write this wrapper by your self - then, yes you should use angular service (or factory) that responsible for holding those socket objs, this service won't die when your controllers will.
When you will change something on the scope as a response to a certain event you should forward the event to the controller, so the controller will register the event but the controller will change the scope. (or himself if your using ctrl as), if that wasn't enough clear, comment below and I will add some code examples.